# How to get a Mac to auto-reconnect to a wifi network?

Tags: mac, wireless-networking

I have a Mac Mini Server that's disconnecting every few days or so from the wifi network. There may be other parameters causing the initial disconnection (such as the wireless router being rebooted) but the Mac doesn't automatically reconnect.

It's a major problem since it's a server machine that's suddenly becomes unavailable until someone goes to the machine physically and uses the wifi menu to reconnect manually to the network. I should mention that although the wifi network is WPA2, manually reconnecting doesn't involve re-entering the password so there's no obvious reason why it doesn't reconnect automatically.

How can I get the Mac to periodically try and reconnect to a specified wifi network?

Comment: Is the network in question defined as Preferred? Have you checked in System Preferences > Network that "Remember any network this computer has joined" is checked and "Disconnect from wireless networks when logging out" is unchecked? You could also try to delete and recreate the network connection.

Comment: where exactly is the "Disconnect from wireless networks when logging out" option? It's running Lion.

Comment: Apparently in Advanced settings.

Comment: not to make you paranoid or anything, but the only way to crack WPA2 encryption is to sniff the authentication packets (when a computer connects) and the most common way to do that is to de-authenticate one of the machines and sniff the network when it re-connects.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is an Applescript and shell script to check if Airport is connected and if not to connect it.

```
if (do shell script "networksetup -getinfo Wi-Fi | grep -c 'IP address:'") = 1 then
    do shell script "networksetup -setairportnetwork en1 <networkName> <passwordToNetwork>"
end if
```

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $(networksetup -getinfo Wi-Fi | grep -c 'IP address:') = '1' ]
then networksetup -setairportnetwork en1 <networkName> <passwordToNetwork>
fi
```

Replace `<networkName>` with the network's name and `<passwordToNetwork>` with its password. The "en1" should be correct if you have not changed your Network devices.

Now all you need to do is loop this or call it to check the connection.

Nevertheless airport should automatically reconnect if the connection is lost. Maybe try resetting all network preferences and see if that works.

How to completely reset your Network Preferences:
Turn Airport off. Close System Preferences.
Navigate to: `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/`
Make a copy, then delete the following files:

```
com.apple.airport.preferences.plist
com.apple.network.*
com.apple.smb.server.plist
NetworkInterfaces.plist
```

Comment: thanks. why use an applescript though? it seems to lend itself more to a shell script perhaps one that runs every minute or so using launchd.

Comment: also, how do you "reset all network preferences" ?

Comment: This could be done with a shell script. Although I'm better at Applescript so I wrote it in Applescript. I'll see if I can write it in a shell script. I've also updated the post on reseting network preferences.

Comment: Improved the script and added a shell script.

Comment: I fixed the most egregious shell script error but it should probably be refactored some more. On my Mac I get two hits from `grep` when it's up and only one when it's down, but it would probably be better to check for something else; counting the number of something is pretty much an antipattern.

Comment: This script works perfectly to reconnect lost wifi signal/connection. Is there a way to auto-activate/run this script every time my mac is disconnected from wifi hotspot?

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to comment on [Kassym Dorsel's answer](https://superuser.com/q/335117/150988#346355), but I don't have enough points to do so.

I had the same problem with my Mac server:

Wi-Fi connects to VPN and Ethernet to LAN, so if the Wi-Fi connection is lost, OS X doesn't automatically reconnect.

Considering Kassym Dorsel's answer:

- I wasn't comfortable having my Wi-Fi password stored in the clear (admittedly it's an extremely low risk, but still).
- I wanted it to enable Wi-Fi if it had been disabled.
- I wanted it to handle the condition where a static IP address was assigned, Wi-Fi was enabled, but it was either still not connected or connected to the wrong Wi-Fi network (SSID).

So I modified his script to address these concerns (replace `<networkName>` with your preferred network SSID):

```
#!/bin/bash

# turn on Wi-Fi if it's turned 'Off'
if networksetup -getairportpower en1 | grep -q 'Off'
    then networksetup -setairportpower en1 on
fi
    
# cycle Wi-Fi power if missing 'IP address'
if ! networksetup -getinfo Wi-Fi | grep -q 'IP address:'
then
    networksetup -setairportpower en1 off
    networksetup -setairportpower en1 on
fi

# initiate connection if not connected to the correct network
if ! networksetup -getairportnetwork en1 | grep -q '<networkName>'
    then networksetup -setairportnetwork en1 '<networkName>'
fi
```

Comment: Similar to the accepted answer, I fixed the most problematic shell programming problems. This is almost elegant now.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for the style updates here (I'm new to bash patterns). Unfortunately, I think switching to the -q flag in the third if statement breaks the functionality. It now reconnects to the desired network when it's already connected. Is there a clean way to negate that if condition while still using grep -q? Thanks!

Comment: There seems to be a logic error in the last condition; it should probably be `if ! networksetup ...`; perhaps see also my separate answer.  I have updated this to reverse the logic now. Probably my mistake when I made the previous edit.

Comment: Probably also be prepared to change the interface name; I have my wifi on `en0`

Answer (score 2):

You might try to play with the `airport` utility (in newer OS X versions it's hidden away in `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport` or a similar path).

Specifically, the `JoinMode` and `JoinModeFallback` preferences could be useful. On my machine, `JoinModeFallback` is set to `DoNothing` by default. Changing it to `KeepLooking` seems a promising start.

Run `airport` without arguments to see its help.

Comment: This was interesting and promising, but did not in the end change anything for me. I changed the preferences (I had "unknown" and "nothing" for fallback) but the WiFi still won't reconnect.

Answer (score 1):

Use ethernet instead. Plug it into a wifi bridge if your human cohabitants don't like the long cable-run aesthetic.

Let's see how many downvotes I get for an 8yr-old question (sadly still relevant!)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple refactoring which works for me.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
networksetup -getinfo Wi-Fi | grep -q Subnet: ||
networksetup -setairportnetwork en1 "$ssid" "$password"
```

Obviously, replace `$ssid` with the actual network SSID and `$password` with the password for this network.